# Issue with loading view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two tables in database (Users and Books) and two models (Models.Book, Models.Users). I created partial view but when I try to load the data from Books a get an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcEntryTask.Models.Books]', 
>       but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcEntryTask.Models.Users'.

I think that in one view can't be 2 models, and thats way error msg appeared. Am I wright? And how to fix that?

Comment: Thanks. I have never worked with ViewModels. I'll look for them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class that specifically binds to your view. This is commonly known as a view model.

Example - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dphill/archive/2009/01/31/the-viewmodel-pattern.aspx

Once the View Model data as been submitted back to the controller, transform it back into your Book/User models.

Comment: Thanks. One question. After creating view model, (new class), do I need to change something in controller or only that view?

Comment: Just the view, although you will need to declare the model on your controller actions if your submitting the data back. You can bind the newly created ViewModel class to the partial view using the `@model` tag.